# Building Butterworth Bandpass Filters

Tags: filtering, signal-processing

In order to bandpass filter data it is necessary to use ButterworthFilterModel, followed by ToDiscreteTimeModel and RecurrenceFilter.  I have two questions:

1. I wish to specify the order of the bandpass filter. However, this does not seem to be possible. How can I do this?
2. There is an option for ToDiscreteTimeModel called CriticalFrequency but there is no mention of prewarping which I understand to be necessary. Does CriticalFrequency  introduce warping? What does it do? Must I warp?

Here is what I have worked out what to do so far. Comments on improvements are welcome. I will generate a filter and then apply it to some data. Finally by using Fourier transforms I will determine the filter I have developed. I start by defining the sample rate I will use and the high pass and low pass frequency values. I also define the attenuation I want at the cut-off frequencies.

```
 sr = 3500; (* Sample rate *)
 f1 = 500; (* high pass frequency (Hz) *)
 f2 = 1000; (* low pass frequency (Hz) *)
 g = -(1/2) 20 Log[10, 
  1/Sqrt[2]]; (* attenuation at cut-off frequencies *)
```

The reason for the 1/2 in the attenuation is that I am going to pass the data forwards and backwards through the filter and thus will get a doubling in the attenuation. 
I now define a warping function for the bilinear transformation which is the default option.

```
ClearAll[wf];
wf::usage = 
 "wf[f] gives the warped frequency in Hz for the desired frequency f \
  in Hz. Frequency must be scaled by sample rate thus values less than \
  0.5 expected.";
SetAttributes[wf, Listable];
wf[f_] := 2/(2 \[Pi]) Tan[(2 \[Pi] f)/2]
```

I also define a helper function to determine the order of the filter I have built

```
ClearAll[filterOrder];
filterOrder[bpf_] := Module[{num, den, n1, n2},
 num = bpf[[1, 1, 1, 1]];
 den = bpf[[1, 2, 1, 1]];
{n1, n2} = Flatten[Exponent[#, Variables[#]] & /@ {num, den}];
{n1, n2 - n1}
 ]
```

Now I wish to build a filter with high pass and low pass orders of, for example, 2. I have to supply values for the two stop frequencies and the two pass frequencies together with attention at the pass and stop frequencies.  I use nominal stop frequencies and the two pass frequencies defined above. I use a value x which I vary until I get the orders I wish. How can I automatically find x?

```
x = 1.5;(* guess; adjust to get target filter orders *)
bpf = ButterworthFilterModel[{"Bandpass", 
 2 \[Pi] {0.9 f1, f1, f2, 1.1 f2}, {g + x, g}}];
filterOrder[bpf]
```

Above I have not used warping. For comparison purposes I repeat the build by first warping the target frequencies

```
x = 1.5;(* guess; adjust to get target filter orders *)
wbpf = ButterworthFilterModel[{"Bandpass", 
sr 2 \[Pi] wf[{0.9 f1, f1, f2, 1.1 f2}/sr], {g + x, g}}];
filterOrder[wbpf]
```

I now make the time domain models using ToDiscreteTimeModel. Here I could have used the option CriticalFrequency but I don't know what it does.

```
fm = ToDiscreteTimeModel[bpf, 1/sr];
wfm = ToDiscreteTimeModel[wbpf, 1/sr];
```

I would like to put all the above into one module. However because I have to adjust the attenuation x by hand this is not possible. 
In order to test the filters we make some data that is rich in frequencies.

```
nn = 100000; (* number of points *)
zv = 250; (* zero values at start and end *) 
data = 
Join[ConstantArray[0, zv], RandomReal[{-1, 1}, nn - 2 zv], 
ConstantArray[0, zv]];
```

The  zero values are to allow for the ringing of the filter. The results of the filtering are

```
filterOutput = 
RecurrenceFilter[fm, Reverse[RecurrenceFilter[fm, Reverse[data]]]];
wfilterOutput = 
RecurrenceFilter[wfm, 
Reverse[RecurrenceFilter[wfm, Reverse[data]]]];
```

The actual filter that has been generated can be determined by calculating the Fourier transform of the output divided by the Fourier transform of the input.

```
fInput = Fourier[data];
fOutput = Fourier[filterOutput];
wfOutput = Fourier[wfilterOutput];
h = fOutput/fInput;
wh = wfOutput/fInput;
freqs = Table[(n - 1) sr/Length[h], {n, Length[h]}];
```

We can now make comparisons

```
p1 = Plot[{Abs[bpf[2 \[Pi] f I] bpf[2 \[Pi] f I]], 
 Abs[wbpf[2 \[Pi] f I ] wbpf[2 \[Pi] f I ]]}, {f, 0, 1500}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Frequency / Hz", "Modulus"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Brown},
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"Target", "Target Warped"}],
 Epilog -> {Pink, Line[{{f1, 0}, {f1, 1.1}}], 
 Line[{{f2, 0}, {f2, 1.1}}]}];
 p2 = ListPlot[{Transpose[{freqs, Abs[h]}][[3000 ;; nn/2]], 
 Transpose[{freqs, Abs[wh]}][[3000 ;; nn/2]]}, Joined -> True, 
  Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Green, Orange},
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"Calculated", "Calculated Warped"}]];
 Show[p1, p2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The pink lines are at the cut-off frequencies. It can be seen that the spectrum calculated using the warped filter (orange)  agrees best with the target filter (blue). Without the warping (green) the calculated filter is badly off. The warped target spectrum (brown) looks wrong but is the one to use.

A possibility for calculating the filter is to use a version of FindRoot. However, the results are integers so this does not work.

Thanks for help in answering the questions.

Comment: The premise of your question is not really right -- there are many ways to design and apply linear filters other than the Butterworth filter. The tutorial here http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DigitalFilterDesign.html has several ways.

Comment: @bills As the title states I am trying to use the ButterworthFilterModel. Having selected this method I am then stuck with my questions. I could use other methods, as you suggest, but I am using the Butterworth method.

Comment: If your goal is to "generate a filter and then apply it to some data", you are taking the long way. Modern filter design methods use techniques other than Butterworth to design the impulse response and then you can apply ListConvolve to do the filtering.

Comment: @bills Butterworth filters have a nice property of being maximally flat in the pass band. I need this property so this is why I am working with these filters. Can you better this property?

Comment: There are many measures of quality of a filter: quality of rejection in the stop band, rapid transition regions, flatness, length of filter, etc. There are tradeoffs. No filter is better in all respects.

Comment: @bills Is this discussion off-topic? I have specific questions about the Butterworth filter; you seem to be suggesting I should look elsewhere. I would like to work with what we have in Mathematica. However, if you can offer a solution for a filter that is maximally flat in the pass band and for which you can control the filter order please post.

Comment: You can't specify the filter order N and both corner frequencies at the same time as requirement of the design. This is conflicting specification.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks. My target is to specify a start frequency a stop frequency and the filter order. In specifying the start and stop frequencies there is also the number of dB that the filter is down from 1 -typically Sqrt[2]. I think I should be able to specify this to get my filter. I am not concerned with the frequencies at which the attenuation bands fall below a level.  I do not see that these are conflicting requirements. What do you think?

Comment: You can't do that. The way this is done, is to design the filter as low pass, then use frequency transformation to map it to bandpass. To design it as low pass and specify the order, you can't also specify the stop and pass corner frequencies and the order. One finds the order of the filter from the corner frequencies and the attenuation. If you want to specify the order, then you have to omit the stop corner frequency. Once you get the low pass filter, then the transformation is one line basically. The formulas are in the books.  But you might want to ask in dsp group on this, I am no expert.

Answer (score 4):

As of version 10 (certainly in version 10.3) you can specify the filter order and the band pass and band stop frequencies. This is what I wanted in my first question.

I cannot find any reference to prewarping. I guess you just have to know that this is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

(to answer the second part)

"CriticalFrequency" is a suboption to the "BilinearTransform" (aka Tustin's) method. Bilinear transformation introduces warping, because it maps the entire imaginary axis onto the circumference of the unit circle. With "CriticalFrequency"->$f$, there is no distortion at frequency $f$.