# high pass filter without losing detail

Tags: filtering, signal-processing

I have troubles doing a simple high pass filtering...

Downloading [the test data](https://pastebin.com/74J8t2YV), you can see that overimposed on the signal there are some low frequencies and an almost constant slope, that I'd like to get rid of:

```
 ListPlot[Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/74J8t2YV", "Table"], Joined -> True]
```

The problem is that using the following code, to have the signal oscillate around a more-or-less constant line I need to use $h_f > 2 \pi / f_\text{samp}$ (Nyquist),
but at frequencies so high the important details of the signal are lost.

```
Module[{dat, a, times, lf, hf = 1, fl, filt, avgy, fsamp},
 dat = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "test.dat"];
 times = dat\[Transpose][[1]];
 a = dat\[Transpose][[2]];
 avgy = Mean[a];
 a = a /. y_ -> y - avgy;  (* not interested in signal offset *)
 
 fsamp = 1/Mean[Differences[times]]; (* sampling slightly irregular *)

  hf = 2 \[Pi] 0.9/fsamp;
 filt = HighpassFilter[a, hf];
 ListPlot[{{times, a}\[Transpose], {times, filt}\[Transpose]}, 
  Joined -> True]]
```

[image: original and filtered data]

I'm not an expert at all in frequency analysis, but I did these kind of stuff blindly using Microcal Origin - and there the highpass filtering does not suffer of this drawback... what can be done?

Here is the results in Origin (the signal is the same, I just forgot to subtract the average)
[image: Origin high pass filter in action]

unfortunately the help page doesnt enter into details about the algorithm, where you only choose the cutoff frequency

Comment: I would recommend taking the first order discrete derivative of the data.

Comment: Relevant for constructing filters 'https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153421/12558'

Comment: The samples you provided don't have a constant time step. You may have to resample or just assume a constant time step (like the average time step, which is 0.0610). Furthermore, how about just fitting a low-degree polynomial and subtracting it to detrend the signal. I would subtract the mean first. Then the trend doesn't look quite linear so maybe fit a quadratic and subtract it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default kernel length of `HighpassFilter` seems to be too small, after modifying it to `Round[Length@a/10]`, the result is almost the same as that of *Origin*:

```
times = dat\[Transpose][[1]];
a = dat\[Transpose][[2]];
avgy = Mean[a];
a = a - avgy;
(* Alternative method for obtaining a: *)
(*
   a = Standardize[dat\[Transpose][[2]], Mean, 1 &];
 *)

fsamp = 1/Mean@Differences@times;(*sampling slightly irregular*)
hf = 0.3;(*Found by trial and error *)

filt = HighpassFilter[#, hf, Round[Length@#/10], SampleRate -> Round@fsamp] &@a;

ListLinePlot[{{times, a}\[Transpose], {times, filt}\[Transpose]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: wonderful, thank you. I notice you added also SampleRate, which I didnt use

Comment: @alessandro AFAIK, setting `SampleRate` is the standard way to tell `HighpassFilter` etc. how many sample is taken every one second. Your approach i.e. directly scaling the cutoff frequency is also valid, of course :)

Answer (score 9):

Here is my take on how to do filtering for a time series. The HighpassFilter you used is I think for [image processing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/91725/12558).

Import the data and find the sample rate

```
data = ToExpression[Partition[StringSplit[Import["74J8t2YV.txt"]], 2]];
ListLinePlot[data]
sr = 1/(data[[2, 1]] - data[[1, 1]])
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The sample rate is 16.9492 and from the data it looks like you have a main frequency at about 0.2 Hz. The data starts at about 3400 units. I am assuming you wish to get rid of the rising drift.  Now check the frequency content by doing a Fourier transform.

```
ft = Fourier[data[[All, 2]], FourierParameters -> {-1, -1}];
ff = Table[(n - 1) sr/Length[ft], {n, Length[ft]}];
ListLogPlot[Transpose[{ff, Abs@ft}][[1 ;; 500]], PlotRange -> All, 
 Joined -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Looking at the first peak this confirms that there is a frequency of about 0.2 Hz.

Now I build a high pass filter. I start with an analogue Butterworth filter of 4th order and with cut off frequency fp which I set to 0.1Hz. You may wish to play with this value to see what frequency is best for you.

```
fp = 0.1; (* filter cut off frequency *)
filter = ToDiscreteTimeModel[ 
  ButterworthFilterModel[{"Highpass", 4, fp 2 π}], 1/sr];
```

Now apply the filter and plot the results.

```
fd = RecurrenceFilter[filter, data[[All, 2]] - data[[1, 2]]];
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], fd}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I have taken away the first point of the data so that the filter is not hit by a big step. This value could be adjusted a little and may take out the low frequency initial oscillation.

Hope that helps.

**Edit**

Following a comment from xzczd I have changed the code for generating the filter by removing division by the sample rate. This is correct there is no need to divide by the sample rate here. Unfortunately the original data has gone so I can't retest the code.

Comment: very detailed, thank you! I'll try to read it in detail to understand it better...

Comment: "The `HighpassFilter` you used is I think for image processing. " Hmm… I think image processing, signal processing, time series processing, etc. have no essential difference. Actually most examples in the document of `HighpassFilter` are **not** related to image, and `HighpassFilter` is listed in the [guide for time series processing](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/TimeSeries.html). Anyway, it's interesting to know how to build a filter in a relatively low level way, +1 :)

Comment: @xzczd If you read the post I linked to I analyse the Lowpass, Highpass and Bandpass filters. The Bandpass seems to do nothing. I agree that filtering is filtering with the purpose of removing frequencies from the data. However,  if you want features designed-in like causality, and precise cut off values (I should have prewarped above for more precision) then there is a vast literature on this and it is good that it is supported by Mathematica. Thanks for the +1.

Comment: +1 for considering investigating the fourier transform.

Comment: Just had a second look on the answer… Is the `fp 2 π/sr` part wrong actually? The value of `fp` is determined based on the fact that there's a peak at about 0.2 Hz in Periodogram, right? Then it should be `fp 2 π` because the cutoff frequency in `ButterworthFilterModel` is the "true" frequency of the signal, and sample rate already has its place in `ToDiscreteTimeModel`. (In this case the result won't have significant change of course. )

Comment: @xzczd  I think it is usual in signal processing to assume the sample rate is 1.  If you use a different sample rate you have to scale your frequencies by the sample rate (effectively making the sample rate=1). I do this in `ButterworthFilterModel`. I then have to take this into account again when I use `ToDiscreteTimeModel`. I could probably have missed these both out and got the same answer. However, a long time ago I decided that I would work with actual frequencies rather than scaled frequencies and this is how I now do it. I also decided to work in Hz rather then radians per second.

Comment: @xzczd There is also the issue of prewarping. I show the need for this in the post connected with [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99919/12558) post.

Comment: I mean, I think you've scaled the frequency repetitively, while you only need to do this once (Either in `ButterworthFilterModel` or `ToDiscreteTimeModel`).

Comment: @xzczd The time step is a required parameter in `ToDiscreteTimeModel`. The [bilinear transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform), which is the standard method, requires the time step. So I think you need the time step (=1/ sample rate) in both `ButterworthFilterModel` and ToDiecreteTimeModel`.

Comment: Well, but the value `0.1` is based on the peak at 0.2 Hz in `ListLogPlot`, right? The "1/(sample rate)" has already been considered here.

Comment: @xzczd The data came with a sample rate of 16.9492. I chose the value 0.1 as the cut-off frequency to be well away from the frequency of interest (0.2). If you chose a larger value for the cut-off frequency then this could modify the frequency of interest. Looking at the spectra before and after filtering would be a useful exercise. A value of cut of frequency of 0.05 might have worked just as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79198/discussion-between-xzczd-and-hugh).

Answer (score 8):

How about `LowpassFilter`ing the signal and subtracting the result from the original?

```
ListLinePlot[
 Transpose[{
   dat[[All, 1]],
   # - LowpassFilter[#, 0.005] &@dat[[All, 2]]
  }]
 , AspectRatio -> 1/5
 , ImageSize -> 1000
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: it works this way too! Possibly LowpassFilter has a larger kernel length?